# Why is Task<HttpResponseMessage> not awaitable in my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I have a project that is targeting the .NET 4 framework and I've created a method which updates data in a database. The method itself also uses a flag (runAsync) to determine whether it should run asynchronously or not. I'm getting an error that 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task< HttpResponseMessage > is not awaitable' but I am using this same code in another application and it works fine.  What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing to get this to work?

Here is the code:

```
public static async Task<object> UpdateData(SecureData data, string userAgent, bool runAsync)
{
    object result;

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = runAsync
                                                ? await client.PutAsJsonAsync(String.Format("api/securedata/update/{0}", data.Token), data)
                                                : client.PutAsJsonAsync(String.Format("api/securedata/update/{0}", data.Token), data).Result;

            result = runAsync
                            ? await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>()
                            : response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>().Result;

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're targeting .NET 4 - do you have the async compatibility pack installed? Normally async/await requires .NET 4.5.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The async compatibility pack should not be used on ASP.NET.

Comment: I'm curious about that runAsync parameter. Can you tell why you are doing that?

Comment: I'm using the runAsync parameter simply to allow the method to be run both synchronously and asynchronously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[You cannot use `async`/`await` on ASP.NET 4.0. You must upgrade to 4.5.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx)

Comment: Oh, I thought async/await was available in both 4.0 and 4.5. Thanks!

Comment: @freakinthesun: It is for desktop/mobile apps, but not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Install Async

Tools --> NuGet --> Packet manager console

run below code

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Version 1.0.168
```

Ref:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async