# Await/Async .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043738/why-is-taskhttpresponsemessage-not-awaitable-in-my-project). [StephenCleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) states not to use Async Compatablity Pack.

When researching this more fully I have come across MSDN posts on how to use it and why, I have come across SO posts on how to use it and best practices, and the NuGet Gallery states that it is designed for .net 4.0

Why would this not be recommended by someone who wrought the book  [Concurrancy and C#](http://tinyurl.com/ConcurrencyCookbook)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.Net 4.0 supports `await` perfectly fine with the compatibility pack.

However, **ASP**.Net 4.0 does not, because it makes far more assumptions about the async model.

Using `await` in ASP.Net requires a better `SynchronizationContext`, which was [added in 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx).

Comment: @gh9: This is exactly correct. Note that the question you linked to is regarding an ASP.NET MVC project, so it should not use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. It's perfectly acceptable to use for desktop applications.